# What type of a relationship should be here

Tags: uml, relationship, entity-relationship, class-diagram

I'm doing class diagram and i have two entities User and Comment
So what type of relationship should be here multiplicity or composition

##
[image]

Comment: Any, as long as you don't tell the context.

Comment: Actually you alread have a property of type `Comment`and below `User`. If you add an N--1 association with roles you should remove them.

Comment: @qwerty_so I agree with the beginning of your remark, but about the end of your remark, in formal/2017-12 page 206 the comment of the fig 11.31 says : *the attribute notation can be used for an Association end owned by a class* ... _**Although it would typically be suppressed on grounds of redundancy, this notation may be used in conjunction with the association notation to make it perfectly clear that the attribute is also an association end.**_ (However I do not allow that in BoUML because I think to have both is heavy, and that complexity implementation requiring associated settings etc)

Comment: @bruno I recommend https://bellekens.com/2011/08/10/uml-best-practice-attribute-or-association/ as a general statement (I support).

Comment: To me an association with a role marked as owned property is the same as having an attribute with the same name. Different rendering of the same thing. I'm used to EA and to that tool both are different entities. When selecting a role name it offers the defined attributes, but only to copy the name, not to internally link both. That's a bad thing. So one should use either the one or the other (in EA; but I guess most UML tools have a similar implementation like that).  I appreciate your restriction in BoUML.